# Speech recognition throws unknown value error

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am a newbie to python speech recognition and whenever I try to transcribe an audio file  using google speech API, I get an unknown value error.

I have tried searching the web for this but am unable to get any method of solving the issue

The complete code and the error is put up on hastebin: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/urugalurak.py

The expected output should,obviously, be the text in the file.

Comment: It can be tedious to debug complete code – it'd help if you could narrow down the error. Please produce a [mcve] and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55566775/edit), pasting the minimal code here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try specifying these additional parameters (skip `key` or use `key=None` if you haven't obtained one):

```
r.recognize_google(audio, key=my_google_speech_recognition_api_key, language='en-US', show_all=True)
```